# How can I get the contact ID

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8.1, addressbookui

I have a problem with getting the contact ID from the address book.

My .m file:

```
-(IBAction)test:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    ABRecordID recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", recordID];

}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I imported the AddressBook and the AddressBookUI into the .h file.
It works all but I get the wrong ID.
Everytime I only get the ID -1 and that stands for error.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot,
Christian

Comment: Okay, I changed it and answered my question with the right solution for the others ;) Thank you for your time and help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 8, it no longer automatically requests permission for the address book when just showing the people picker. (The idea is that is that the picker, alone, is not really giving the app access to your contacts, so no permission should be required. It offers low-friction UI when app isn't really getting the contact details.)

But, in your case, you really are trying to programmatically retrieve information about the contact. For that, you do need permission. So, prior to presenting the picker, you might want to ask permission to the address book:

```
ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
if ((status == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted)) {
    NSLog(@"User previously denied permission; show error message that they must go to settings and give this app permission");
    return;
} else if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    CFErrorRef error;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
    if (!addressBook) {
        NSLog(@"unable to open address book: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
        return;
    }

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"OK");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not ok");
        }

        CFRelease(addressBook);
    });
}
```

Comment: By the way, note that that authorization completion block does not run on the main thread, so any UI stuff you do inside that block must be dispatched back to the main queue.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works for me :) With my solution and the work from Rob, you can get the ID of a contact ;)

Comment: This worked for me too.  With the change above ABRecordGetRecordID stopped returning -1 (kABRecordInvalidID) as it had before.  The docs say it ABRecordGetRecordID returns kABRecordInvalidID "when the record hasn’t been saved to the database."  To that I would certainly add: "kABRecordInvalidID is also returned if the app has not yet requested access to the address book using ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(...).

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution how to get the ID of a contact:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
    if ((status == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted)) {
        NSLog(@"User previously denied permission; show error message that they must go to settings and give this app permission");
        return;
    } else if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        CFErrorRef error;
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        if (!addressBook) {
            NSLog(@"unable to open address book: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
            return;
        }

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                NSLog(@"OK");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Not ok");
            }

            CFRelease(addressBook);
        });
    }

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    ABRecordID recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"], recordID);
}
```

Thanks to Rob who helped me out :)